# Holes for HD Screw Anchors

Tags: tools, masonry, fastener

I've ordered [5/8" x 4" Strong-Tie Titen HD Screw Anchors](https://www.fastenersplus.com/products/5-8-x-4-Strong-Tie-Titen-HD-Screw-Anchor-Zinc-Pkg-10) to secure a pull-up rig to a brick wall.  See photos.

The brick wall is actually a solid 1 foot thick!

What's the best way to drill holes for these kinds of anchors?

I want the roundest and closest possible to 5/8" hole.

I've considered:

- SDS-plus
- Rotary Percussion
- Double Flute or
- Standard rotary masonry bits.

Great if answers could also explain the differences and advantages of the various ways to do this.

[image]

Comment: What kind of brick, 1' thick.?  I would use a sleeve or a wedge anchor instead.

Comment: @AlaskaMan - About 4" thick, so 3 courses make up the 1 foot think wall.

Comment: Brick are not that solid. I think the treads on the HD screws may not provide enough holding power. I would use a **dedicated brick anchor**. This video is informative. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4e9dQO8bLmI

Comment: You seem to be asking about the precision of masonry bits, which is a bit odd since bazillions of holes have been made with them specifically for such anchors. Much of what you posted up there is irrelevant to that. Please refine your post to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: @isherwood -- Do you suggest that all masonry bits have equal precision?

Comment: I'm suggesting that precision with respect to roundness isn't terribly important, and that masonry bits round off to blunt hammers before long anyway, but they still do their job. I'm also curious what alternatives you had in mind. I know of none for holes of that size. Larger holes allow for core drills, but I don't know that they're inherently more _precise_.

Comment: If you're after precision with respect to _location_, piloting with a small bit can help prevent walk-off.

Comment: I agree with Isherwood, all of the bits you listed do the same. Different locking mechanism on the bits for some but a standard 2 flute reduced shank bit in my 1/2” Milwaukee hammer drill will do the same as my hilti the difference the hilti is a professional tool that will do the job in 1/4 the time. No difference in the roundness of the holes.

Answer (score 0):

You're free to use any method you desire to make holes in brick. Most construction folk will use a standard 2-cutter masonry bit. If they need to make a really *big* hole and don't care quite how precise it is, they'll use a jack hammer.

There are diamond tipped hole saws available for coring into masonry, but they're rather expensive and I'm not sure you'd find one at only 5/8" diameter.

Comment: Guess _someone_ didn't like my answer. _haz a sad. gets over it quickly_

Comment: The down vote wasn't me but I have never seen a jackhammer used for a “hole” when considering putting a pipe in a wall a core drill is used and these are actually much rounder than any of the rotary hammer bits most of those I have are carbide.